# The tag [nazi] is redundant with [nazism] and [nazi-germany]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [nazi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazi) is redundant with the tags [nazi-germany](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazi-germany) and [nazism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazism). In addition, it’s rather ambiguous in meaning: while the other two tags refer to a specific period in Germany’s history, and a specific ideology, “nazi” looks like an adjective looking to combine with another tag. We should get rid of the tag.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of burnination puns. I didn’t feel like one for this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a glance, it appears that [nazi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazi) is slightly more often misused for questions relating to the general ideology than the specific regime of Nazi Germany. I have therefore merged it into [nazism](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazism), and also synonymised the two, which should prevent future uses of the [nazi](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nazi) tag.